# How do I reflect a dotnet web api endpoint that uses query string parameters in SwagggerUI?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore, aspnet-api-versioning

I'm trying to implement a dotnet web api with API versioning that uses query strings and headers. Here im using swagger to document and test the endpoints. I successfully used path versioning and reflected the endpoints in swagger. But im struggling to understand how to reflect query string & header versioning in swagger. I tried to find a solution from this article https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#query-parameters but was still confused how to implement this in my dotnet web api.

My project contains 2 main controller classes with the following API versions.

1. WeatherForecastController.cs

   ```
    namespace QueryStringVersioning.Controllers
    {
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiVersion("1.1", Deprecated = true)]
    [ApiVersion("3.0")]
    [Route ("api")] //support query string & header versioning
    // [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")] //support path versioning 
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", 
    "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }


    [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("3.0")]
    public IActionResult GetV3_0() => Ok(new string[] { "MapToApiVersion value 3.0" });

    [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("1.1")]
    public IActionResult GetV1_1() => Ok(new string[] { "Depreceated MapToApiVersion value" });
    }}
   ```
2. WeatherForecastController2.cs

   ```
    namespace QueryStringVersioning.Controllers2
    {
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [ApiVersion("2.1")]
    [Route ("api")] //support query string & header versioning
    // [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")] //support path versioning 
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
    public IActionResult GetV2_0() => Ok(new string[] { "This is API Version 2.0" });

    [HttpGet, MapToApiVersion("2.1")]
    public IActionResult GetV2_1() => Ok(new string[] { "This is API Version 2.1" });
    }}
   ```

And the startup.cs file

```
    namespace QueryStringVersioning
    {
    public class Startup
    {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {

            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "API_Versioning V1",
            });

            c.SwaggerDoc("v1.1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1.1",
                Title = "API_Versioning V1.1",
                
            });

            c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v2",
                Title = "API_Versioning V2"
            });

            c.SwaggerDoc("v2.1", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v2.1",
                Title = "API_Versioning V2.1"
            });

            c.SwaggerDoc("v3", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v3",
                Title = "API_Versioning V3"
            });
            
            c.ResolveConflictingActions (apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First ());
            // c.OperationFilter<RemoveVersionFromParameter>();
            // c.DocumentFilter<ReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPath>();
             
            
                    
        });
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddApiVersioning(option =>
        {
            option.ReportApiVersions = true;
            option.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            option.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            // Supporting multiple versioning scheme
            option.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new HeaderApiVersionReader("X-version"), new QueryStringApiVersionReader("api-version"));
            
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API_Versioning V1.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.1/swagger.json", "API_Versioning V1.1");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "API_Versioning V2.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2.1/swagger.json", "API_Versioning V2.1");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v3/swagger.json", "API_Versioning V3.0");
        });
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: You could find the solution of [Web API versioning using the NuGet packages from Microsoft](https://samanthaneilen.github.io/2019/01/19/Web-API-versioning-using-the-NuGet-packages-from-Microsoft.html).

Comment: @MichaelWang thanks a lot! This article guided me to what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

@michael-wang is correct. You need to also include the [API Versioning API Explorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer/) extensions. This extensions make API discovery API version *aware*. One of the many possible uses for this information is OpenAPI/Swagger integration.

Links to all of the applicable NuGet packages are listed on the [API Versioning](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) landing page. There is also an [end-to-end example](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerSample) provided using Swashbuckle.